# singular or a plural verb after "и..., и ..."?

Tags: грамматика

Do I need to place a singular or a plural verb after "и..., и ..."?

For example:

> И Россия, и Франция вxод(**и/я**)т во Всемирную Торговую Организацию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a plural.

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию, [§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)*:

> При повторяющемся союзе сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа, например: *И тот и другой способны на это.*

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to put comma in "И тот и другой" or comma is not needed there?

Comment: @brilliant: not needed, it's an established phraseologism (look 87.3 by the same link).

Answer (score 2):

You should use plural form of the verb here:

> И Россия, и Франция вxод**ят** во Всемирную Торговую Организацию.